# How do I create a color picker?

Tags: c#

This is the code I have so far:

```
private void btnColour_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //show the colour dialog and check that user clicked ok
        if (clrDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //save the colour that the user chose
            c = clrDialog.Color;
        }
    }

Color c = Color.Black;
```

Isn't it supposed to be working? maybe I have selected the wrong event?

Comment: What is `clrDialog` is that your class or a .NET framework built in class? What steps did you do to connect `btnColour_Click` to the `Button.Click` event? Please explain how your code is not working.

Comment: Well what happens? What is `c`?

Comment: And what happens? Does the event never get called, does the event get called but the dialog does not show up, does the dialog show up but your color is not saved in `c`?

Comment: well the program runs there aren't any errors but when the button is pressed nothing happens

Comment: When you put a breakpoint in the function does the breakpoint get hit and the debugger stops when you click the button?

Comment: No. I put it near the method. it didn't hit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create the Dialog in the event handler instead of outside, try something like this:

```
private void btnColour_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ColorDialog clrDialog = new ColorDialog();

    //show the colour dialog and check that user clicked ok
    if (clrDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //save the colour that the user chose
        c = clrDialog.Color;
    }
}

Color c = Color.Black;
```

Comment: From the comments, it sounds like the click event isn't wired up to the button.  Might want to help the user with that, too.

Comment: Try this [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwwsdtbk(v=vs.80).aspx) to make sure btnColour_Click is the event handler for your button.